# In selenium python webdriver, I'm not able to download a text file with a .lst extension

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, download

I'm relatively new to python webdriver and I've been trying to use this code to make it so I can download a text file with a `.lst` extension:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)  
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir","/my/directory")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/lst") 
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

This has worked fine when I've needed to download a zip file and used "application/zip" as the file type to download.  Con someone tell me what I would need to get this file downloaded?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: use mime-type `text/plain` instead of `text/lst`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out using the steps outlined here:

http://watirmelon.com/2011/09/07/determining-file-mime-types-to-autosave-using-firefox-watir-webdriver/

Using these steps, I determined that my mime file type is 'application/forced-download'  So my code now looks like this:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)  
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir","/my/directory")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/forced-download") 
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

And my file downloads without any human interaction.  Thanks to @alecxe for your help and patience ;)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, and according to this [MIME Types list](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/), you should try the following:

```
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/plain,application/x-powerpoint")
```

You can also **switch to Chrome** and make it automatically download files:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {
    "download.default_directory" : "/some/path",
    "download.directory_upgrade": "true",
    "download.prompt_for_download": "false",
    "disable-popup-blocking": "true"
}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't do it alecxe.  Is there a setting that says something like 'just download any type of file'?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user4476068 nope, you have to explicitly specify the mime-type(s). Can you upload a sample file for me to test? Thanks.

Comment: @user4476068 well, an easiest option could be to upload a sample file to a file sharing hosting.

Comment: @user4476068 also, would you be okay to switch to Chrome?

Comment: Here's the file:   [link]http://www.filedropper.com/junk1  Do you mean switch my tests to Chrome? Once I get things running in firefox, one of my next tasks will be to also make them run in chrome.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @user4476068 from what I see `text/plain` should work for you..I've also updated the answer with a Chrome-specific option, please test. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again @alecxe.  I can hopefully spend some more time with it today, and I'll be sure to hang onto your chrome example.

Comment: Does it matter how the download button launches the download?  The code for the button in the test that's giving me problems looks like this:     <input type="button" onclick="document.location='../../lib/download.php?id=k_30819bc3d6bfa75290e44b6&amp;zip=n'" value="Download 'test.lst'" class="nav_button">
and when I've done this successfully in other tests, the code for the download button looks like this:  <input type="submit" value="Download" name="DownloadSubmit" id="DownloadSubmit" class="dwnld_button">.  Would this difference make my initial firefox options not work right?

Comment: @user4476068 yeah, it can be related. Did chrome option work for you? Also, is there any way to share the link to the web-site you are testing against for me to play around? Thanks.

Comment: It does work in chrome!  I wonder why it's not working in firefox?  Unfortunately, I can't give you access to the site I'm working on.

Comment: @user4476068 at least this is because Chrome doesn't need to be provided with an explicit list of mime-types. Consider accepting the answer since we at least came up with a workaround here. Glad to help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Firefox + Selenium 3x +python3 on Windows.
My code for download without modal window

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile ()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Your\\Folder")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",   "application/zip")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

where `application/zip` is definition of your MIME type.
Maybe it will help someone

Comment: This is an almost exact rehashing of OP's code in question with no significant changes that would be helpful.