# How to Save in PDF Format Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium to automate some pdf files downloads. However, I ran into a problem where I need to click on the save button in the following pop up window.

[image]

I couldn't find any method to click on the save button using Selenium. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: did you try to click Enter using Selenium or configure your browser so it would start download without prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use gecko driver

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_porfile import FirefoxProfile()
profile = FirefoxProfile()
# Save pdf without asking
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf")
```

You can find other files subtitles

> https://www.sitepoint.com/mime-types-complete-list/

edit:
I find a similar link here:

[In selenium python webdriver, I'm not able to download a text file with a .lst extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28181102/in-selenium-python-webdriver-im-not-able-to-download-a-text-file-with-a-lst-e)